# Is there any way for a toggle to operate on a member of a binding?

Tags: swiftui, combine

So let's say I have a data type like this:

```
struct Foo {
   var isOn: Bool
}
```

And I want to have a toggle which operates on the `isOn` member - something like this:

```
struct MyView: View {

    @Binding var model: Foo

    var body: some View {
        Toggle("is on?", $model.isOn)
    }
}
```

Is there any way to achieve this, or would I have to make `Foo` an observable object with each member being published?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't use the argument label. Fix that to make it compile and it will work fine.

```swift
Toggle("is on?", isOn: $model.isOn)
```

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
  @State var model = Foo(isOn: false)

  var body: some View {
    MyView(model: $model)
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah perfect, thanks!